# Subspace that contains a particular vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W \in R^4$ be the smallest subspace that contains the vector $(0,1,1,-1)$ and the vectors $ (t,0,t-1,t+2)$ for every $ t \in Z$

Find a base and the equations of $W$

A base of $W$ is:

$ W = \langle(0,1,1,-1),(t,0,t-1,t+2)\rangle$

The dimension is $dim W = 2$ for every $ t \in Z$

Now I have to find the equations which means that I have to find a system of equations which solution is the subspace $W$

I can do it by row reducing this matrix:

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        t & 0 & x \\
        0 & 1 & y \\
        t-1 & 1 & z \\
         t+2 & -1 & w \\
        \end{pmatrix}=
$
$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        t & 0 & x \\
        0 & 1 & y \\
        -1 & 1 & z-x \\
         2 & -1 & w-x \\
        \end{pmatrix}=
$
$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 1 & z-x \\
        0 & 1 & y \\
        0 & t & x+tz-tx \\
         0 & 1 & 2z+w-3x \\
        \end{pmatrix}=
$

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 1 & z-x \\
        0 & 1 & y \\
        0 & 0 & x-ty+tz-tx \\
         0 & 0 & -3x-y+2z+w \\
        \end{pmatrix}=
$

So

$W =
\begin{cases}
x + t(-x-y+z)=0,  &  \\
-3x-y+2z+w, &  \\
\end{cases}$

I would like to know if it is solved correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This is not correct:  $W = \langle(0,1,1,-1),(t,0,t-1,t+2)\rangle$.  It would be correct to say $$W=\mathrm{span} \{(0,1,1,-1)\} \cup \{(t,0,t-1,t+2)\}_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$$ but the right-hand side will not be a basis (it has too many vectors).
- This is the wrong matrix to be working with to find a basis
  $$
          \begin{pmatrix}
          t & 0 & x \\
          0 & 1 & y \\
          t-1 & 1 & z \\
           t+2 & -1 & w \\
          \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  it should (a) be the transpose (so the row operations are consistent with linear combinations of the vectors), (b) not have $x,y,z,w$ (variables like this would be outside of the matrix in a system of equations written $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$,or omitted entirely when writing it as $[A|\mathbf{b}]$) and (c) contain rows for different values of $t$.

---

By definition these vectors belong to the space:

- $(0,0,-1,2) \in W$ (when $t=0$) and
- $(1,0,0,3) \in W$ (when $t=1$),

and we can see these, along with $(0,1,1,-1)$ are linearly independent.  So maybe $\{(0,1,1,-1),(0,0,-1,2),(1,0,0,3)\}$ is a basis.

To show this, we need to check that for arbitrary $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ we can find $a,b,c$ such that $$(t,0,t-1,t+2)=a(0,1,1,-1)+b(0,0,-1,2)+c(1,0,0,3).$$  I.e., all the vectors in the set that generate $W$ can be written as linear combinations of these three vectors.

We do this by solving the system of linear equations (each equation is formed from each coordinate above)
\begin{align*}
0a+0b+c &= t \\
a+0b+0c &= 0 \\
a+(-1)b+0c &= t-1 \\
(-1)a+2b+3c &= t+2 \\
\end{align*}
treating $t$ like some unknown number.

One of two things may happen:

- If there is a solution for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $$\mathrm{span}\{(0,1,1,-1),(0,0,-1,2),(1,0,0,3)\}=W$$ so we've found a basis.
- If there's not a solution for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, then a value of $t$ for which there are no solutions will give another vector we need to add to set to give a basis.